# Get the type of a function parameter with boost::hana

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-hana

I know how to get the type of a function's parameter the old way, but I was wondering if there is a nice new way to do it with Hana? For example, I want something like this:

```
struct foo {
    int func(float);
};

auto getFuncType(auto t) -> declval<decltype(t)::type>()::func(TYPE?) {}
getFunType(type_c<foo>); // should equal type_c<float> or similar
```

How do I get the `TYPE` here?

Comment: Have you look at [boost_functiontypes/components](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html#boost_functiontypes.reference.decomposition.components) ?

Comment: No I have not, I will look into it. How well does it scale? It seems to still use MPL as its back end, which I am trying to avoid due to compilation time.

Comment: The proposed [Boost.CallableTraits](https://badair.github.io/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html) is the modern solution if you don't want to roll your own, AFAIK.

Comment: I assume you are aware your problem cannot in general be solved, and you are asking for some limited solution?

Comment: Yes, just constrained to doing it for a specific arity for a specific function name. Although after looking at CallableTraits, it seems like a much easier problem to solve that way. Although not really the answer I was looking for originally, I'll post it if there is no better answer.

Comment: I'd like to mention that this would be out of scope for Hana, as Hana does not provide any traits itself. What it does is provide a way to use existing traits (e.g. from `<type_traits>`) using function syntax, but it does not define any new ones.

Comment: All the library writers are here now! Thanks for the info, I'm still getting my bearings on the capabilities of Hana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit 6/21/2016 - Minor changes to match current version of library (0.4).

I'm the author of CallableTraits, the library mentioned above by @ildjarn (although it is not yet included in Boost). The [`arg_at_t`](http://badair.github.io/callable_traits/doc/html/callable_traits/reference.html#callable_traits.reference.parameter_list_features.ref_arg_at) metafunction is the best way that I know to get the parameter type from a member function, function, function pointer, function reference, or function object/lambda.

<strike>Please keep in mind that the library is currently undergoing significant changes, and that the linked documentation is somewhat outdated (i.e. use at your own risk). If you use it, I recommend cloning the [develop branch](https://github.com/badair/callable_traits/tree/develop). For the feature you are seeking, the API will almost certainly not change.</strike>

For member function pointers, `arg_at_t<0, mem_fn_ptr>` aliases the equivalent of `decltype(*this)`, to account for the implicit `this` pointer. So, for your case, you would do this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <callable_traits/arg_at.hpp>

struct foo {
    int func(float);
};

using func_param = callable_traits::arg_at_t<1, decltype(&foo::func)>;

static_assert(std::is_same<func_param, float>::value, "");

int main(){}
```

Then, you can put it into a `boost::hana::type` or whatever your use case requires.

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2ikJW9vD53i1Oeyv)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what can be expected to be stable and what is slated to be changed in the library? Apart from the documentation, can I assume the general functionality will remain or will there be significant overhaul?

Comment: @user975989 Since I don't have room to answer your question here, I answered it in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/badair/fb310dd0ce18685ad9a57958d1bb3950).

Comment: @user975989 I updated my answer to reflect changes from the most recent version.